# How do I get WorkboxPlugin to cache my index.html if I manually set chunks?

Tags: angular, webpack, progressive-web-apps, html-webpack-plugin, workbox

In my GenerateSW config, I am manually specifying the Webpack chunks that I want precached:

```
chunks: [ // Precaching
    'runtime', 'angular',
    'rxjs', 'tslib',
    'webpack', 'zone.js',
    'app', 'styles'
],
```

How do I include the index.html in here, if it's not a Webpack chunk?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding the index.html as an entry, then using ChunkRenamePlugin to rename it to "index.html" (removing hashing and js extension), so that the entry isn't included in HtmlWebpackPlugin.

```
entry: {
    index: './src/index.html',
}
new ChunkRenamePlugin({
    index: 'index.html'
}),
new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW({
chunks: [
    'index', 'runtime', 'angular',
    'rxjs', 'tslib',
    'webpack', 'zone.js',
    'app', 'styles'
]})
```